# Asterisk ARI Caller id is always Anonymous

Tags: asterisk, voip, asterisk-ari

I'm trying to make a outgoing call using asterisk and stasis.

From my app, i send a simple post to **/ari/channels/create**, like this:

```
params = {
  endpoint: `PJSIP/${trunkPrefix}${numberOriginal}@${trunkName}`,
  app: 'stasisApp',
  channelId: uuidv4(),
  appArgs: `digital,"${JSON.stringify(appArgs).replace(/\"/g, '\\"')}"`,
  formats: 'ulaw',
};
url = `http://${asteriskHost}/ari/channels/create`;

const variables = {
  'CALLERID(num)': callerId,
};
  
(async () => {
    await axios.post(url, {
    variables,
  }, {
      auth: {
        username: '',
        password: '',
      },
      params,
    }).then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(({response: {data}}) => {
    console.log('Error', data);
  });
})();
```

Then, i do dial() on the channel, but asterisk sets the From parameter like this:

```
 From:  "Anonymous" <sip:anonymous@anonymous.invalid>
```

I need to be able to set the callerid on outbound calls, i tried using **CONNECTEDLINE(number)**, but isnt working either, also tried to set the callerid using **/channels/{channelId}/variable** endpoint, but when the call goes out, the From header is still anonymous. Any ideas?

I'm using asterisk 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, after creating the channel I was doing another things before using `dial()` method, nothing fancy, just creating a bridge, start a recording on the bridge and putting another channel on the bridge, but apparently something during those operations made the `callerid` on the original channel go away, I just did an request to `setChannelVar` endpoint with `CONNECTEDLINE(num)` just before the `dial()` and it worked.

Thanks for the help